# How to edit processes queued using && in Linux/bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Lets say I have 3 processes queued in a Linux/Shell terminal by separating the commands for respective processes using **&&** as follows:

```
<command1> && <command3> && <command4>
```

Now while command for process1 was being executed, I want to edit the queue:

---

e.g. 1:
I want to have another process2 in between process1 and process3. So that the updated command queue becomes:

```
<command1> && <command2> && <command3> && <command4>
```

e.g. 2: Or may be remove a process for e.g. process3 from the queue. So that the updated command queue becomes:

```
<command1>  && <command4>
```

Is there a way to edit the command queue on the fly? i.e. when the process1 is already being executed?

Comment: There's no way to do this. There's no queue that can be manipulated.

Comment: Implement your own *queue manager* which manually starts processes after analysing the exit status of the last one terminating, instead of using `&&`.

Comment: Barmar, for better visibility, can you please post this as an answer, instead of a comment?

Comment: You might look at how `execline` works. A program can control what happens after it *if it's responsible for executing those things itself*.

Comment: (and it's perfectly possible to write a turing-complete language for expressing such constraints. I'm cheating and making things less flexible by using a hardcoded sigil in my answer below, but such hacks aren't necessary -- using a length-prefix mechanism, for instance, allows the mechanism to be built with zero constraints on program contents; the execline approach of prefixing child arguments is also workable).

Comment: @Anand, have you managed to evaluate any of the answers provided below? Does any of those help you?

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about [command list](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists) in `bash` (not queue), and once the shell parses it, you can not modify it.

It's not clear from the question whether you really need a queue, or a simple exit status testing will serve you, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash
if cmd1; then
    cmd2
else
    if cmd3; then
        cmd4
    fi
fi
```

(This would first run `cmd1` and then, depending on its success, run `cmd2` if it succeeded, or try running `cmd3`, followed with `cmd4`. The last if block can be simplified to `cmd3 && cmd4`.)

But, if you really need a command queue, you'll have to implement one yourself.

#### Try 1: simple array queue

The first idea is to store your queue in a shell array variable, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a queue

clear() { queue=(); }

is_empty() (( ! ${#queue[@]} ))

# insert an item at the beginning
insert() {
    queue=("$1" "${queue[@]}")
}

# append an item at the end
push() {
    queue=("${queue[@]}" "$1")
}

# remove an item from the beginning
pop() {
    queue=("${queue[@]:1}")
}

# return the first item, without popping it
peek() {
    echo "${queue[0]}"
}
```

and then use it for running commands like this:

```
# run commands from the `queue`
run() {
    while ! is_empty; do
        local cmd=$(peek)
        pop
        eval "$cmd" || return
    done
    return 0
}

# run: echo before && sleep 1 && echo after
clear
push 'echo before'
push 'sleep 1'
push 'echo after'
run
```

But the major problem with this approach is **you can't really modify this queue asynchronously**. You can modify it before running, or while running *inside the `run` loop*, but that's probably not what you are asking for.

You might be thinking, why can't we execute commands in background with `run &`. Well, we could, but then the background subprocess (subshell) would receive its own copy of the `queue` variable, and the modifications you do after spawning would not be reflected in the `run` subprocess.

#### Try 2: simple file queue

Another approach is to implement your queue in a file, by storing one command per line. This would actually work, but we would also need to ensure some mutual exclusion mechanism is in place (for example `flock`).

While this approach works, I don't like the idea of rewriting the complete file each time you need to insert a command in position 0. You could keep the file in memory, though, by creating it on `/dev/shm` (ramdisk), but that wouldn't work on MacOS.

#### Try 3: Redis queue

Logical extension of the previous approach is to use an actual shared in-memory queue, like the one provided with [Redis](https://redis.io/).

`bash` wrapper for this Redis-based queue would be:

```
#!/bin/bash

redis=(redis-cli --raw)

clear() {
    "${redis[@]}" DEL queue &>/dev/null
}

is_empty() (( $("${redis[@]}" LLEN queue) == 0 ))

# insert the item at the beginning
insert() {
    "${redis[@]}" LPUSH queue "$1" &>/dev/null
}

# append the item at the end
push() {
    "${redis[@]}" RPUSH queue "$1" &>/dev/null
}

# remove the item from the beginning
pop() {
    "${redis[@]}" LPOP queue
}

peek() {
    "${redis[@]}" LRANGE queue 0 0
}

show() {
    "${redis[@]}" LRANGE queue 0 -1
}
```

And you could run your first example (with insertion while the previous command is running), like this:

```
# run commands from the redis queue
run() {
    while ! is_empty; do
        eval "$(pop)" || return
    done
    return 0
}

# start with: echo before && sleep 1 && echo after
clear
push 'echo before'
push 'sleep 3'
push 'echo after'

run &

# but then, 1sec after running, modify the queue, insert another command
sleep 1
insert 'echo inserted'

wait
```

Example output:

```
$ ./redis-queue-demo.sh
before
inserted
after
```

---

#### The solution for your examples

So, using the Redis approach, your **first example** (inserting a command) would look like:

```
clear
push 'echo command1; sleep 2'
push 'echo command3'
push 'echo command4'

run &

sleep 1
insert 'echo command2'

wait
```

Output:

```
command1
command2
command3
command4
```

The **second example** (removing a command):

```
clear
push 'echo command1; sleep 2'
push 'echo command3'
push 'echo command4'

run &

sleep 1
pop >/dev/null

wait
```

outputs:

```
command1
command4
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running `command1 && command2 && command3` at the shell, move the logic *into the command that makes the decision what to run*. Thus:

```
command1 --c1-arg1 --c1-arg2 -- command2 --c2-arg1 -- command3
```

...where each command has logic akin to:

```
command1() {
  local arg1=0 arg2=0
  local -a next_command=( ) extra_args=( )
  while (( $# )); do
    case $1 in
      --c1-arg1) arg1=1 ;;  # example
      --c1-arg2) arg2=1 ;;
      --) shift; next_command=( "$@" ); break;
    esac
    shift
  done
  # ...now, let's say we wish to conditionally add a comand4 to the end of the list:
  if (( arg1 && arg2 )); then
    if (( ${#next_command[@]} )); then next_command+=( -- )
    next_command+=( command4 )
  fi
  # regardless, shift control to our next command if it exists
  (( ${#next_command[@]} )) && exec "${next_command[@]}"
}
```

That way, you aren't trying to have your command modify the state of the shell (its parent process), but are simply having the command modify *its own variable*, the array `next_command`.

Answer (score 0):

As the people(Barmar & Patrick) have already commented, there are no ways to manipulate when the command 1 is on execution.

After execution of  you can check for the status of command using $? (or) you can use any other logic that you are looking for. Using which you can build your queue respectively.

```
<command1>
if [ $? eq 0 ]
then
   #on success
   <command2> && <command3> && <command4>
else
  #on failure
  <command4>
fi
```

Comment: `command1; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then foo; else bar; fi` is better written as `if command1; then foo; else bar; fi`.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, valuable comments